# ¿Cómo puedo conectar al servicio web SII de la Agencia Tributaria, con WCF, .NET 6 y Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, soap, wcf, aeat-sii, .net-6.0

No consigo conectar con éxito a la web de la Agencia Tributario, protocolo SOAP, mediante WCF Web Service, para los temas relacionados con el SII, Suministro Inmediato de Información.

Mi aplicación, escrita en Winforms NetFramework 4.8, funciona perfectamente y comunica sin problemas, ahora estoy haciendo la migración a .NET 6 y la parte de comunicación ya no funciona.

En NetFramework 4.8 se usa el archivo app.config que contiene información relevante para la comunicación, con .NET 6 ese archivo ya no se utiliza, Microsoft informa del cambio con este mensaje:

system.serviceModel section is not supported on .NET 6 (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-a-sample-wpf-app-to-net-core-3-part-2/#updating-wcf-client-usage)

He subido un ejemplo a `https://github.com/j-tomas/AgenciaPruebas`

Por si alguien puede ver el código y aportar un poco de información.

Gracias por anticipado,
Tomás.

Comment: Me parece que tu error está en la autentificación (te da un error 403) y por lo que entiendo el servicio te retorna una página con este error en vez de un XML (que sería lo normal), esto provoca otro error, ya que el tu aplicación espera un XML.  Por otro lado en tu código hay algo que me causa ruido: `cliente = new siiSOAPClient(siiSOAPClient.Endpo.....` En esa altura el objeto siiSOAPClient es nulo. Te recomiendo sacar el endpoint del constructor y cambiarlo directamente desde el archivo ConnectedService.json

Comment: Gracias @Yussef, yo también estoy convencido al 99% que el problema está en el certificado, de alguna manera parece que el certificado no está funcionando bien.

Comment: Lamentablemente tu problema no es reproducible, así que solo podemos darte concejos (y no te extrañe que tu pregunta sea cerrada por este motivo). Cuando un WS está hecho en JAVA (y me parece que este es el caso) y el cliente en .NET existen problemas, JAVA no implementa SOAP correctamente. Lo que se hace en este caso es editar y cambiar los atributos (decoradores [ ] ) a mano de las clases autogeneradas por .NET hasta encontrar la configuración correcta. Si tú ya tienes un proyecto en .net 4.6 funcionando, puedes tomar las clases de ese proyecto

Comment: Además creo que es mejor que primero te ocupes de la conexión con el WS como si fuera fija y cuando te haya resultado eso, te ocupas que sea variable (a producción o a testing). También te comento que ha salido .net 7 y ya que estás haciendo un upgrade puede que te interese ocupar esta versión a otra que al día de hoy ya es "antigua"